# Can I access Sintra settings outside of the website's application class?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Inside the `Website` class I can obtain root as `settings.root`. Outside the class I don't see how to get a handle to the class object.

I could insert a instance variable `@root = settings.root` inside the route block which would make root available the HAML. Is this the proper way?

```rb
 class Website < Sinatra::Base
    configure do
      set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)
    end
    get '/' do
      haml :index, :layout => :base
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the proper way is to use the `:locals` hash as a parameter of your `haml` call, like this:

```
class Website < Sinatra::Base
  configure do
    set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)
  end
  get '/' do
    haml :index, :layout => :base, :locals => {:root_path => settings.root}
  end
end
```

In your view's templates, you'll have access to a `root_path` variable.

Comment: Excellent! I can access it as `locals[:root_path]`